# WSL expected to be in the same environment but isn't

Tags: windows-10, wsl2

I have Windows 10 (10.0.19043.1288), and I installed WSL2 using `wsl --install ubuntu` (20.04) from an elevated (admin) PowerShell.

I set the default WSL version to 2 and selected Ubuntu as the default distribution.

When starting using `bash.exe` (which is in `c:\Windows\system32`):

```
$ whoami && id && uname -a    
root  
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
Linux COMPUTERNAME 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When starting with `wsl.exe` (which is in `c:\Windows\system32`):

```
$ whoami && id && uname -a
root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
Linux COMPUTERNAME 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When starting with `ubuntu.exe` (which is in `c:\Program Files\Apps\Cannonical...`):

```
$ whoami && id && uname -a
uid=1000(username) gid=1000(usernamegroups=1000(username),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),117(netdev),1001(docker)
Linux COMPUTERNAME 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The output of `wsl.exe -l -v`:

```ps
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION  
* Ubuntu                 Running         2  
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2  
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
```

Questions:

- Why do I have different environments? Ubuntu is selected as default.
- Why do I have a `bash.exe` and `wsl.exe` in the `system32` directory?

Comment: @ClimbTheWorld - The difference in the environment appears to be connected to the user, try setting the default username to the desired username instead of root. You should be made aware that 21H1 (19043) is near unsupported status by Microsoft. "Why do I have bash.exe and wsl.exe in the system32 directory?" - Why exactly do you expect these system files NOT to exist in a system directory?

Comment: Ok, a few more questions -- How long ago did you install?  Last couple of days?  It's possible that there's a bit of a "new release"/"new bug" in play here, but not sure yet.  Does `wsl --version` return anything other than the help?  Try running it in an elevated PowerShell also -- Is the result any different?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds The installation was done this week (new staged).

Comment: @ClimbTheWorld Thanks - I'm still trying to picture what could be causing this.  There's a new WSL release that could theoretically cause two different environments to be installed at once, but it's only available for newer Windows releases (at least ending in `.2311` -- With [KB5020030](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/november-15-2022-kb5020030-os-builds-19042-2311-19043-2311-19044-2311-and-19045-2311-preview-237a9048-f853-4e29-a3a2-62efdbea95e2) installed).  Without that, I'm not sure why one WSL2 environment would have a different kernel than another, even under different users.

Comment: @ClimbTheWorld Any results with the `wsl --version` under both a regular and elevated PowerShell?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds $ `wsl --version`  says is a invalid option --version followed by help.